# elastic search percentile of aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, percentile

I have an index with 3 fields: user_id, count, timestamp.

I would like to be able to aggregate count by user_id, which is easy with elastic search, however, what I also want to be able to do is a percentile rank on this resulting data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it may be achieved using **Pipelined Percentiles Bucket Aggregation** which is a sibling pipeline aggregation which calculates percentiles across all bucket of a specified metric in a sibling aggregation. The specified metric must be numeric and the sibling aggregation must be a multi-bucket aggregation.

A percentiles_bucket aggregation looks like this in isolation:

```
{
    "percentiles_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "the_sum"
    }
}
```

The following snippet calculates the sum of all the total monthly sales buckets:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "sales_per_month" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "month"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "sales": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "price"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "sum_monthly_sales": {
            "percentiles_bucket": {
                "buckets_paths": "sales_per_month>sales", 
                "percents": [ 25.0, 50.0, 75.0 ] 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the following may be the response:

```
{
   "aggregations": {
      "sales_per_month": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key_as_string": "2015/01/01 00:00:00",
               "key": 1420070400000,
               "doc_count": 3,
               "total_sales": {
                   "value": 50
               },
               "t-shirts": {
                   "doc_count": 2,
                   "sales": {
                       "value": 10
                   }
               },
               "t-shirt-percentage": {
                   "value": 20
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string": "2015/02/01 00:00:00",
               "key": 1422748800000,
               "doc_count": 2
               "total_sales": {
                   "value": 60
               },
               "t-shirts": {
                   "doc_count": 1,
                   "sales": {
                       "value": 15
                   }
               },
               "t-shirt-percentage": {
                   "value": 25
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```